# How to reset iCloud status of a song when using apple music

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, apple-music

iTunes stopped uploading my own (i.e. not from the iTunes store) music after 5Gb out of 50GB.  The rest of the tracks have the `iCloud status Waiting` in the get info box in the File tab.

On my iPhone (iOS 8.4) the tracks appear in my Music grayed out, meaning they can not be played.

Is there some way to reset the iCloud status of these tracks so they can be uploaded?

[image: album]
[image: iCloud status]

Edit:
There no option in the right click menu to add it to the iCloud Library. Also if Click `Remove download` it greys out the track. If I try to play the track, it fails to redownload the track from the cloud, since it was never uploaded.

[image: right click menu]

Using: OS X 10.10.4, iTunes 12.2, iOS 8.4

Answer (score 6):

Try the menu item File > Library > Update iCloud Music Library.

[image: screenshot of Update iCloud Music Library]

I had quit iTunes after initially enabling iCloud Music Library in preferences when it was only partially done uploading.  To get it going again I used this menu item Update iCloud Music Library, the progress indicator in the upper right appeared and it continued uploading.  This was on OS X 10.10.4 and iTunes 12.2.0.145.

Comment: This fixed an identical problem for me. Thank you!
Clicking on the progress indicator (the "throbbing circle") pops up an info box with upload status, so you can follow the process.

Comment: Kind of works for me. It uploads more tracks, but some of the tracks are still not done.

Comment: Choosing "Update iCloud Music Library" does nothing for me. My songs that are in "Error" state remain so.

Answer (score 0):

I had to untick iCloud music library, close prefs, then reopen it and it started syncing again. Briefly it also let me right click a song and upload to iCloud music library, but that didn't seem to do anything

Edit:

1. Click on **iTunes**
2. Click **Preferences...**
3. Uncheck "iCloud Music Library (*yourappleid*)"
4. Click "OK"
5. Click on **iTunes**
6. Click **Preferences...**
7. Check "iCloud Music Library (*yourappleid*)"
8. Click "OK"

Comment: I always find the idea of switching off iCloud services and turning them on again a _really_ scary solution, if indeed it does work. For the case of a single song file, you are disconnecting up to 99,999 others. iCloud is flaky enough as it is without trusting that it'll accurately reconnect all my library files without messing up their metadata or getting duplicates. Thanks, but no thanks!

Comment: By doing this I got some of playlists duplicated i.e Rock => Rock1 and so on, this could not be a problem if it was to just remove the duplicated lists, but instead some of the songs in it went missing which drive me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps:

1. Click on **iTunes**
2. Click **Preferences...**
3. Uncheck "iCloud Music Library (yourappleid)"
4. Click "OK"
5. Click on **iTunes**
6. Click **Preferences...**
7. Check "iCloud Music Library (yourappleid)"
8. Click "OK"